# Prototypal inheritance in javascript, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

This is my code:

```
var Quo = function(string) {            //This creates an object with a 'status' property.
    this.status = string;
};
Quo.get_status = function() {
    return this.status;
}
Quo.get_status = function() {
    return this.status;
}

var myQuo = new Quo("confused");        //the `new` statement creates an instance of Quo().

document.write(myQuo.get_status());     //Why doesnt the get_status() method attach to the new instance of Quo?
```

When I run this code the result is `[object Object]`. My question what properties of a constructor are inherited by an instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question what properties of a constructor are inherited by an instance?

Anything in `Quo.prototype` will be available to the instance.

This code should make your example work:

```
Quo.prototype.get_status = function() {
    return this.status;
};

Quo.prototype.get_status = function() {
    return this.status;
};
```

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_constructor_prototype
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

Comment: @Matt--what properties are contained in the prototype object by default?

Comment: @codeninja - it's a chain. By default you have everything from `Object.prototype`, but it is possible to "extend" from others. Take a peek at the MDC articles I linked

Comment: @Matt--so when Quo is created, Quo.prototype is empty? Or does it contain the properties of Quo?

note: i havent looked at the MDN articles yet.

Comment: @codeninja - when you create Quo itself (NOT the instances), the `Quo.prototype` is technically empty. Prototypes are chains, so when a quo instance doesn't find what it wants, it looks in the next prototype in the chain (in this case, it looks in `Object.prototype`).

Comment: @codeninja - np. on your way out, just to give you an idea of the flexibility of prototypal inheritance .. prototypes are checked dynamically at property-lookup-time. So you can modify `Quo.prototype` at any time and all instances (future _and_ existing) will be affected.

Comment: @Matt--so if I have multiple `Quo.prototype` statements, the last one will be the one that is expressed, regardless of what the others say?

Comment: @codeninja - no, it acts like a regular object .. you can add or remove properties to the prototype at will, and your instance will have access to it. This is of course assuming you don't reassign e.g. `Quo.prototype = someOtherObject`